# What load testing tool(s) are used on stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion

I am looking for a good load testing tool for websites on the Microsoft stack.  What tools are you using specifically for load testing?

**EDIT**

Maybe I should open this to what tools users use in their own projects if there is no tool-based load testing done on SO.

Comment: Ironically I would remove the portion specific to SO and then flag this for, belongs on StackOverflow.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/ does not report a load testing tool; questions about load testing a program belong on SO proper.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect we are the load testers. I have never heard any mention in the podcasts or on the blog regarding Jeff and co doing any load testing apart from the live results on the servers themselves and parsing the logs daily.